# SwiftyJSON how to append data

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I try to create JSON with this structure:

```
    var json: JSON = [
        "params": [
            "token":  Utilities.token,
            "language":   "RU",
            "billerId":   biller.id,
        ],
        "data":   [
            "serviceData": [
               //I want put here additional data
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

in "serviceData" I want to add fields and values, but I don't know how much them and what is his name before compiling.

I try add this fields by this way:

```
    for item in templateItems{
        let key:String = item.name
        let value: String = item.value

        json["data"]["serviceData"][key] = value
    }
```

according to https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/a1356035d2de68c155d05521292f0609ef7e69bb#literal-convertibles

but it doesn't work

It shouldn't be array, it is key-value dictionary.

Comment: Matthias, It doesn't

Comment: Is the `seviceData` (missing an `r`) a typo when you copied it here, or is that in your original code?

Comment: You probably want to use `[:]` to define the empty dictionary

Comment: Jcaron, thank you! It works, it all works!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget the accept and/or up vote the answer if it proved useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
        "seviceData": []
```

With

```
        "serviceData": [:]
```

The former defines an empty array. The latter defines an empty dictionary.